# Can I Open a chart with URL in DynamicsCRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I want to open chart with a URL in DynamicsCRM online.
I understood how to open forms, views and reports from MSDN below.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483(v=crm.7).aspx

I can do it when I open the view with the URL and select the cart tab on the right.
But I want show the chart immidiately after the page loaded.

Is there any a nice way to open a chart directory?
Or would it better to create a report including the chart?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to force the chart pane to open when linking to a view in CRM.

Instead you could create a dashboard (which can contain both charts and views) and link directly to the dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.　　
The licenses my customer have is not professional (on-pre 2013).
It has no function show system dashboards.
But I' trying to show a chart in a web page　with URL (' Like ' a dashboard without it).
Maybe it's too difficult or impossible?